# In another process address space, calling functions in dlls, how to

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, dll, dll-injection

Ok, so I have a dll injected into a target process address space.  How do I return a list of the functions provided by a dll that the target process is using, lets say user32.dll; then lets say that user32.dll contains a function called (int test1(str 1, str 2))  (I know it doesn't) and I want to call that function, how would I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to do all the stuff you wrote? Getting the list of exported functions by a dll is not trivial, after getting the module address in memory you have to walk several data structures of the PE format, which is not so easy to do manually (although the [DbgHelp functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679291%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) automate most of the process).

On the other hand, if you just want to check if a dll is loaded and call one of its function the work gets easy.

If you don't care if the dll has to be loaded, just call [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get the module handle; otherwise, call first [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will provide you a handle to the module if is loaded, `NULL` if it's not, and, if you want to continue, after that call `LoadLibrary` (`LoadLibrary` increments the reference count of the dll, so you're sure the dll won't get unloaded in the meantime).

Then, to check if the procedure you need is present and get its address, use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); notice that usually C functions like the ones exported by Windows dlls are exported just by their name, not by their signature (in C overloading doesn't exist); if you want to call C++ procedures exported with decorated names you have to specify the mangled name.

`GetProcAddress` will return you a pointer, that you'll have to cast to a function pointer with the correct signature of your function; now you're done, just use it to call the function and don't forget to call [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to decrement the reference counter to the dll.

Notice that all this stuff cannot be done safely from the inside of the `DllMain` of your injected function; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674736/loading-a-dll-from-a-dll/2686042#2686042).

Comment: To answer your questions, yes.  I'm having a go and I will tell you how far I get :)

Comment: @flavour404: well, then you should really study the DbgHelp functions; doing that work by hand isn't impossible, but it's quite error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to use DependencyWalker. You will get all imports of each dll in the process.
Of course, this approach wouldn't cover dynamic calls with LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress but to cover it you'll need to hook LdrLoadDll / GetProcAddress to get the exact functions that the process / dlls attached are using.
It's not a big deal but it takes some time.