# Limitation on usages of global variables in DLL (for Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, dll

First of all, I know global variables are evil :) However, there is legit case why I need to use one.

I know that there are very strict limitation on what can be executed in DllMain (no LoadLibraries, no COM initialization and so on).

And I know that global variables are initialized just prior DllMain DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

Do I have the same limitation while global variable initialization?

I found Microsoft article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988ye33t
However, it doesn't have any details related to the limitations.

I saw also another Stackoverflow questions: [What happens to global variables declared in a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701/what-happens-to-global-variables-declared-in-a-dll)
Here is snippet from there "There are things that are forbidden to do in the DllMain. Those things are **probably** forbidden, too, in the constructors."

However, it looks like commentor isn't sure whether such limitations are really exist.

I would appreciate any information on this subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674736/loading-a-dll-from-a-dll/2686042#2686042) of mine, the real dll entrypoint (i.e. the real `DllMain`) is taken by the CRT, that, on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, initializes its stuff, calls the constructors of the globals and then call the "fake" `DllMain` (i.e. what you as a programmer see as `DllMain`).

The MSDN documentation calls `DllMain` the *real* dll entrypoint, so all the restrictions apply also to the constructors of global objects, since they are called by it.

This is yet another reason to avoid globals: the code in their constructors is called from `DllMain`, but this is not evident, so in case of problems coming from doing "forbidden" things in `DllMain` it may take a lot of time before acknowledging that the offending code is in such constructors.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It is perfectly clear answer, which doesn't leave any room for guesses.