# Code executed by shared library when loaded/unloaded

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

Is it possible to create a function in a shared library (.dll on Windows, and .so on linux) that is executed right when the library is loaded (or unloaded)?

Just like the main() function is the entry point for an executable, can I define a function to execute when the DLL is loaded, or unloaded?

E.g.:

```
void _atstart()
{
    // Initialize some stuff needed by the library
}

void _atexit()
{
    // Release some allocated resources
}
```

I think I've seen such an example somewhere, but I couldn't find it any more, and couldn't find anything on the internet about this.

If it is of any use, I'm compiling the code with MinGW.

Comment: See also: [Automatically executed functions when loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759880/automatically-executed-functions-when-loading-shared-libraries)

Comment: See also: [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For windows you can use `DllMain`:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved
);
```

The second parameter `fdwReason` specifies if the library is loaded or unloaded. Full reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // code for library load
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // code for library unload
        break;
    }
    return (TRUE);
}
```

For Linux you might be able to use:

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
__attribute__ ((destructor))
```

but this only came up after a google search, so you have to investigate by yourself - http://tdistler.com/2007/10/05/implementing-dllmain-in-a-linux-shared-library

Comment: So this means that DllMain is executed twice, once when loaded, and once when unloaded?

Comment: @Tibi yes. With different params,

Comment: Keep in mind that you [can't do much inside DllMain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686042/214671).

Comment: My plan is to set up a pipe, and start up a new thread which will process a queue. Functions in the library will add messages to the queue, and another application will receive the data.

Comment: You are fine as far as you use only functions from `kernel32.dll` or stuff that is surely loaded when your dll is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

In C++ you can at least create a global instance of some class

```
class ResourceHolder {
public:
    ResourceHolder() {
        // at start
    }

    ~ResourceHolder() {
        // at exit
    }
};

ResourceHolder theHolder;
```

Some awareness is required though if you use another global variables in your library.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said, under Window you can work from `DllMain`. But be careful what you will do since there is a lot of restrictions (use of COM `CoInitialize` function is forbidden, for instance). One thing you can't rely on is that there is no guaranty in what order dll will be loaded/unloaded, so you must not call functions from your `DllMain` that resides in an other of your dll : it can works today, but not tomorrow :)

More online on the MSDN :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx]

Patrice

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows you can write your own version of DllMain().