# What is HMODULE?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a small problem. I have loaded DLL into the process (it's not mine) and I have to use function inside it. I have got offset to this function so only what I have to do is to get DLLs address and add to it the offset to get to the function. `GetModuleHandle()` returns `HMODULE` variable but actually I don't know what `HMODULE` is. Is it address of loaded DLL or some kind of other mark?

And if it's not address of place where DLL is loaded, how can I get this address? I hope I make myself clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method that you propose will work fine.

It seems that you have injected a dll into a target process and wish to obtain the address of a function in that dll in the target process from the process that injected the dll.

I assume that you also have the dll loaded in the process that injected the dll into the target process and that you want to create a remote thread in the target process and get it to execute the target function in the target process.

Since the dll that you have injected may not be loaded at the same address in the target process as it is in the injecting process you cannot simply use the address that you would obtain from calling GetProcAddress on the function in the injecting process.

An HMODULE is just the DLL's base address (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/557859/7925) for details). So you can take the HMODULE of the dll in your injecting process and subtract it from the address returned by GetProcAddress on your function. You can then add the HMODULE of the injected dll in the target process to this offset to get the address of the target function in the injected dll in the target process. Assuming this function has the correct signature, pass it as the thread function to your call to create the remote thread and you are now running the target function in the target process.

I explain this in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162050/createremotethread-loadlibrary-and-postthreadmessage-whats-the-proper-ipc-me/1163681#1163681).

Comment: Thanks. I've got another problem. When i'm doing like this -> http://wklej.org/id/700802/ i'm getting wrong sum. Should i do it like that -> http://wklej.org/id/700803/ ??

Comment: @Blood: Neither of those things make any sense. You've added the offset (to go from the base to the function) but forgot to subtract it (to get the base in the first place). See my answer. Since you have to do both, and they cancel out, you might as well just not bother.

Comment: David, the only time it cancels out is if the dll is loaded at the same base address in both processes. Otherwise my answer works and yours doesnt :).

Comment: Blood, your problem is that you need to add the HMODULE of the dll in the target process; the easiest way to get this is simply to capture the return value of the remote thread that you started which called LoadLibrary to inject the dll into the target process.

Comment: @LenHolgate: Where did a second process come from? His question doesn't involve two processes as far as I can tell.

Comment: "I have loaded DLL into the process (it's not mine)". I thought the question could be phrased better, which is why I explained my understanding of his question in my answer. Though reading that phrase again it could equally be that the DLL isn't his - but I would have expected him to correct me rather than mark the answer as correct - who knows...

Comment: Can you double check this? On 64 bit I remember casting a HMODULE to a pointer and found that the DLL wasn't there.

Comment: Joshua, do you have code that shows the failure? This method has worked for me for years; though you may need to read this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163681/7925

Answer (score 4):

Call [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The offset cancels out, as you'd have to both add it (to get to the function) and subtract it (to get the base address), so you might as well not bother.

Answer (score 3):

It is similar to the `void*` returned by the POSIX `dlopen()` function (it might even be a typedef - but I don't know that for sure). You pass it to [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an argument. When you are done you also pass it to [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to unload the DLL.

Comment: typedef void *HANDLE; typedef HANDLE HMODULE; so HMODULE is void*.

Comment: typedef PVOID HANDLE; typedef void *PVOID; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types